# Unable to Create a Project in Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, cloud, google

I am creating first project in Google Cloud. But it seems I can not proceed because of the following error:

```
You've gone over GPU global quota by 1 GPU. Please increase your quota in the quotas page.
```

Please see a screenshot of the page below:

[image]

I tried checking the "Quotas Page" but no help. Please see below screenshots:

[image]

[image]

My objective is to train a PyTorch network on GPU. That's it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select the quota you wish to increase (tick the box in front of the line), then press the "Edit quotas" button.

Comment: Thank you very much. _tick the box in front of the line_, you mean the table? it is unselectable. Hovering the mouse over says the following:

*Please be aware that free trial accounts for Google Cloud have limited quota during their trial period. In order to increase your quota, please upgrade to a paid account by clicking "Upgrade my account" from the top of any page once logged in to Google Cloud console.*

My objective is to train a PyTorch network on GPU. That's it!

Comment: During free trial, you can't request a quota limit, and so you can't use any GPUs. You need to upgrade to a paid account to do so.

Comment: So, in other words, may I say that GPU can not be used in a free trial?

Comment: Yes, this is the case. According to the [Google free trial offer](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/free-cloud-features), you can't add GPUs to VM instances while on free trial.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Time to say Goodbye to Google Cloud!